# How to create Global Js function using Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to generate following html/js using angular 2+ as a output is there way to do it ?

index.html
app.js

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />     

    <script type="text/javascript" src="function-file.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
function meetNowCallOnly(){
   console.log('clicked');
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? The angular docs are very intuitive on starting an app.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for the build process of Angular. In angular you can do two kind of builds, JIT and AoT. You can have a look at https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: Please extend your answer by at least explaining what AOT and JIT are since you've already mentioned it. It's more of a comment than it is and answer at th moment. But anyway, the title and your remark have nothing in common. OP is asking about creating global funcions, not about ways to compile Angular app. I fail to see how these two are related.